# Select All MySQL Data Before Provided Date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a small PHP Application which is supposed to allow a user to enter a 4 digit year into an XHTML web form and return all the information saved in the MySQL database with a lower year than the one provided. The years are stored in the db under the column `yearPublished`. I have the query working and I get no errors, however no data is being returned.

Here is the SQL file for creating the database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
`ISBN` char(13) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`author_firstName` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`author_lastName` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`genre` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`publisher` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`yearPublished` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`price` float DEFAULT '0.0',
PRIMARY KEY (`ISBN`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And here is the PHP code that executes the query:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submitForm'])) {
    $strBookPubYear = $_POST['pubYear'];

    if(empty($strBookPubYear)) {
        print("<p class='error'>You must enter a 4 digit publication date!</p>\n");
    } else {
        if(!is_numeric($strBookPubYear)) {
            print("<p class='error'>The publication date must be numeric.</p>\n");
        } else {
            if(!(strlen($strBookPubYear) === 4)) {
                print("<p class='error'>The Publication date must be exactly 4 characters long.</p>\n ");
            } else {

        $sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT yearPublished FROM books WHERE yearPublished < '$strBookPubYear'");

        if($sqlQuery === false) {
            print("<p class='error'>Could not execute the query, please try again.</p>\n");
        } else {
```

notice the `$sqlQuery` variable that is supposed to get all the data where the `yearPublished` is lower than `$strBookPubYear`. I have read multiple tutorials on this, but they all are using the MySQL 'Date' data-type. In my case I am using a text data-type. Please do not tell me to use mysqli, this specific project does not require me to use mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your yearPublished is stored as a varchar, which is essentially a string.  Therefore, when you say `yearPublished < '$strBookPubYear'`, it probably is not doing what you think that it is doing.  Store yearPublished as an INTEGER.  Either way it takes 4 bytes.

You can manually cast the varchar to a number in the query, and it should probably start working.

```
SELECT yearPublished FROM books WHERE (yearPublished+0) < '$strBookPubYear'
```

OK, that wasn't really the problem!  Try this error checking block, to spit out some better clues:

```
// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$sqlQuery) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    die($message);
}
```

Comment: Try the different error block, mysql_error() might yield some better clues!

Comment: Did you solve this problem?  I would be curious to know what it was, and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Your biggest problem in the database is here:

`yearPublished varchar(4) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,`

YearPublished should at least be an Integer or better an actual Date datatype.

Using a varchar datatype, which is a string datatype, this SQL never returns any values:

`$sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT yearPublished FROM books WHERE yearPublished < '$strBookPubYear'");`

The less than symbol, `<` cannot compare if a string value is "less than" some other string value.

**Update**

If you can't alter the structure of the table, you can use MySQL's [CONVERT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) to convert between data types.

So something like this should work:

`$sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT yearPublished FROM books WHERE CONVERT(yearPublished, SIGNED) < CONVERT($strBookPubYear, SIGNED)");`

Since `$strBookPubYear` is a string coming in from the form submit, you'll need to convert that too.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, however the SQL file is one provided and I cannot change it for the sake of functionality. Is there anyway to do this without changing that data-type?

Comment: You can force mysql to parse the varchar into a number on a per-query basis.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can do that or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Updated with MySQL CONVERT() example.

Comment: I showed one way to do it in my answer.  By doing `(yearPublished + 0)`, mysql has to convert yearPublished to a number to add 0.  This may be of dubious utility, because mysql is *supposed* to convert to numbers for the `<` operator for the same reason.  The method shown above with `CONVERT()` is hands down the more correct way to do it.  +1 to the author :)

Comment: The mysql docs [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_less-than), say this about conversion operators < > <= >= ...: "Comparison operations result in a value of 1 (TRUE), 0 (FALSE), or NULL. These operations work for both numbers and strings. Strings are automatically converted to numbers and numbers to strings as necessary."

Comment: So then my original method should work correct? I tried using `CONVERT()` but had no success. I am still not getting anything returned.

Comment: Can you run a simple query using CONVERT at the MySQL console? If you run "SELECT yearPublished FROM books WHERE CONVERT(yearPublished, SIGNED) < 2008" do you get any results there? There might be an issue with how to correctly enter the PHP value "$strBookPubYear" into the query string you're sending in from PHP.1